# Inserting Column From Into Another Table Trough Query

Tags: sql-server-2005

How do I update the Range field of of this table below

[image]

(don't mind the '1' values from the range above, it's supposed to be *NULL*)

with the Range values of this table below

[image]

When I inner join the table with the other on their EquipmentCode the values are doubled like this:
[image]

This was the query I used:

```
SELECT 
  C.*, 
  R.Range AS RangeFromOtherTable 
FROM 
  EquipmentCalibrationRef AS C
INNER JOIN 
  Range AS R 
ON 
  R.EquipmentCode = C.EquipmentCode
```

Comment: The `EquipmentCode` is not unique. How do you determine what row from table2 should update what row in table1?

Comment: And please post your query as well.

Comment: supposedly by 'EquipmentCode' and 'Some other column' but I don't have that 'some other column' to use to make it distinguishable. I was thing of just getting all the values of the 'Range' Column from table2 then just include it to table1 regardless of its 'EquipmentCode'

Comment: @Kurusu - The reason your values are doubled is precisely because you don't have a 1 to 1 relation between your two tables. You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to alleviate this somehow but the results would be matched semi random.

Comment: Also, you have two rows with Equipmentcode 1234 in your second table but only one in your first. What would the expected result be?

Comment: @Lieven the ROW_NUMBER should do even if it's random. As for the 1234 value, I do expect values like that to be doubled but for the rest since their number isequal with the other table it shouldn't be doubled. Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a start, you can use following statement to get a pseudo 1 to 1 match

```
SELECT  ecr.*, r.[Range]
FROM    EquipmentCalibrationRef ecr
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  RefNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EquipmentCode ORDER BY [Range]), *          
          FROM    [Range] r
        ) r ON r.RefNo = ecr.RefNo AND r.EquipmentCode = c.EquipmentCode
```